# Why calling useState update function through other function passed as prop to child component won't work?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is the parent Component.

```js
export default function CanvasPanel(props) {
  const [sketchCoordinates, setSketchCoordinates] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sketchCoordinates);
  }, [sketchCoordinates]);

  const onAddPoint = function (mousePos) {
    setSketchCoordinates([
      ...sketchCoordinates,
      { x: mousePos.x, y: mousePos.y }
    ]);
  };

  const onPrintObject = (toPrint) => {
    console.log(toPrint);
  };

  return (
    <div className="canvas-panel">
      Points:
      <hr />
      {sketchCoordinates.join(", ")}
      <Canvas
        sketchCurveCoordinates={sketchCoordinates}
        addPoint={onAddPoint}
        printObject={onPrintObject}
      />
      <Sidepanel createPoint={onAddPoint} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the child Component

```js
export default function Canvas(props) {
  const getMousePos = function (event) {
    const offset = canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: event.clientX - offset.left,
      y: event.clientY - offset.top
    };
  };

  const handleOnMouseUp = (event) => {
    const mousePos = getMousePos(event);
    props.printObject(mousePos);
    props.addPoint(mousePos);
  };

  return (
    <div className="canvas-container">
      <PureCanvas
        handleOnMouseUp={handleOnMouseUp}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the PureCanvas component

```js
export default class PureCanvas extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <canvas
        className="canvas"
        width="750"
        height="500"
        onMouseUp={this.props.handleOnMouseUp}
      ></canvas>
    );
  }
}
```

The code is not complete as I removed all canvas related stuff because it doesn't really matter, but it has enough to explain and reproduce the behaviour. The addPoint function should append an object with x and y properties to the sketchCoordinates array through spread operator and the update function from useState. This works when calling `addPoint({x: (any int), y: ({any int})` at the CanvasPanel component, but when calling at the Canvas component through props it works only once. The array appends the first element but then it just replaces that same element with a new one, when it should append that element. So, I know I could do this with classes but I can't understand why it won't work with hooks. The following image shows the console after some updates to de sketchCoordinates array:
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G42n6.png)

**EDIT**

Please consider this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-sutherland-noq8k?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) for further enlightenment.

Comment: typo when writing the question, sorry... Fixed already, thanks mate.

Comment: 1. You should be referencing `props`, not `this.props`. 2. You're referencing `this.props.handleOnMouseUp`, which isn't a prop.

Comment: Another writing mistake fixed, hopefully there aren't any now! First post, I'm really sorry.

Comment: The focus is the hook as I mentioned, does anything come to mind?

Comment: What hook are you referring to? The only hooks you're using are `useState` and `useEffect`, and the latter isn't doing anything.

Comment: I'm referencing the setSketchCoordinates, the spread operator isn't working properly. You can try by yourself copying my code.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be an issue with anything specific to the hook: if we replace the `<canvas>` with a button that just calls `handleOnMouseUp` on click, it works as expected.

I suspect it's not anything to do with the hook, and perhaps it's some detail that's been simplified out of your example:

[Here's a code sandbox with this simplified version, that replaces the canvas with just a button](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-bush-8kx9t?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I can see it worked with the button but I really need it to work on the canvas... What do you mean with "detail that's been simplified"?

Comment: I created [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-sutherland-noq8k?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) for enlightenment.

Comment: Your code sandbox appears to work?  I click and points appear on mouse up, is that not the behavior you're expecting?

Comment: Nope, there should be a line connecting the points stored in the `sketchCoordinates` array. But as you can see on top of the canvas and on the console these points are just replacing the `sketchCoordinates[0]` position instead of being appended as stated in the `onAddPoint` function at the CanvasPanel component.

Comment: You can check [this other code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-fermi-9qy1u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to understand its appropriate behaviour.
The whole question is why
`setSketchCoordinates([
      ...sketchCoordinates,
      { x: mousePos.x, y: mousePos.y }
    ]);`  
doesn't work when the `onAddPoint` is called at the Canvas component but works when called by clicking the button at the Sidepanel component.